# What am I doing wrong with my use of the GDB 'find' command?

Tags: gdb

First, the bit of memory I'm looking at:

```
(gdb) x/8x 0x108df0
0x108df0:  0x36393735  0x2d007d37  0x65707974  0x6574203a
0x108e00:  0x702f7478  0x6e69616c  0x6863203b  0x65737261
```

Now, running find for word-sized chunks of memory works:

```
(gdb) find /w 0x108df0, +500, 0x6863203b, 0x65737261
0x108e08
0x108e58
2 patterns found.
```

However, running what I think should be the same command in terms of bytes does not:

```
find /b 0x108df0, +500, 0x68, 0x63, 0x20, 0x3b, 0x65, 0x73, 0x72, 0x61
Pattern not found

find /b1 0x108df0, +500, 0x68, 0x63, 0x20, 0x3b, 0x65, 0x73, 0x72, 0x61
Pattern not found
```

Similarly, looking for giant words also doesn't work:

```
find /g 0x108df0, +500, 0x6863203b65737261
Pattern not found
```

Does anyone have any advice for what I'm doing wrong here?
(I'm doing this through the python API, in case that's relevant?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely performing this exercise on a [little-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Little-endian) machine.

Try reversing the bytes:

```
find /b 0x108df0, +500, 0x3b, 0x20, 0x63, 0x68, 0x61, 0x72, 0x73, 0x65
```